# Quick launch visible back after published dashboard to Sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

We have a performancepoint services Business intelligence site, in this we dont need quicklaunch and top link bar for dashboards, so i have done this by adding the script in the content editor and hiding it, after doing this the quicklaunch/left navigation and top link bar have been hidden/removed. But when published the dashboards back to sharepoint site the left navigation and top link bar reset/unhidden.

Please suggest me how to make them hidden permanently even we do publishing the dashboards.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have a PerformancePoint dashboard, you can add webparts inside of it. It sounds like you have done this by adding a webpart with custom css to hide those elements.

The problem with doing this is when you edit that dashboard PerformancePoint can take hold of that page and relay the webparts. Thus your webpart is no longer included in that page.

One option is editing your [PerformancePoint site's masterpage or css](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh127349(v=office.14).aspx) for that site to remove those elements.

Another option would be to a stand alone webpart page within that site and deploy your [PerformancePoint Content as individual web parts on the page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Getting-acquainted-with-PerformancePoint-dashboards-and-Web-Parts-894fa23b-8fa4-47e8-9bcf-605a9f2604ef?CorrelationId=533b40fc-7758-4730-a737-281848ac0bf5&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). In my experience this becomes painful when you use lots of connected filters, since you will have to manually wire them up.